# How do I make a while loop store consecutive variables each time it's run?

Tags: python

I'm new to Stack Overflow and Python. I'm trying to make a kind of translation program, I'm sure there is an easier way than what I'm doing, but hey that's part of learning. So basically the user inputs the letter, then the answer is translated, and printed. But I'd rather store it instead of print it, so that I can print the answer altogether at the end if that makes sense.

```
`a = "b"
While True:
  i = input()
  if I_1 = a:
    L_1="a"
  if I_1 = b:
    L_1 = "b"`
```

etc..
So i want `L_1` to be stored each time, as `L_1`, `L_2` etc so at the end i can say

```
`print(L_1 + L_2)`
```

and so on.

I know I've probably used bad conventions but hopefully it's clear enough to understand.
Thanks.

Comment: append the values to a `list` - https://www.thegeekstuff.com/2013/06/python-list/

Comment: You need to use `==` for equality comparisons.  A single `=` is an assignment operator.

Comment: Create a list `result = []`.  To add a new value to the end, use `result.append(value)`.

Comment: The question is unclear. Please clarify what `I_1` `I_2` `L_1` `L_2` are. Also where are you using `i = input()`. Give an example of what your intended output for a given set of input is.

Comment: Thanks guys! It's all good I understand now, just didn't know that lists could be appended. Now just gotta figure out how to print it aesthetically.

Comment: @JoshZylstra look at https://pymotw.com/2/pprint/

Comment: Try something like: `print("Translated letters are {}".format(', '.join(output_data)))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it with the help of a list, which is a python built-in array like data structure. You can append the result to it everytime. You can break the while loop by typing a certain string or character etc. 
Again you need to correct your operators, while loop (W is capital).

At the end to print it, you can use join which returns a string in which the elements of sequence have been joined by str separator. More about it here: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/join-function-python/

```
a="b"
b="a"
lis=[]
while True:
  i = input()
  if i == a:
    lis.append("a")
  if i == b:
    lis.append("b")
  if i=="exit":
      break

print("".join(lis))
```

Good Luck!

Answer (score 1):

It is *possible* to do it that way (programmatic generation of variables), but it's generally considered very bad form, because it makes it difficult to reason about which variables refer to what in your program.

Instead, consider using a `dict`. Like a `list`, it is a container, but unlike a `list`, you access its elements with *keys*, which can be, in particular, strings. This is very helpful for your usecase since you can put the *results* of translation in the `dict` and access them with the *original* characters/words/phrases.

You also need ways to note input that isn't recognised and to end the loop (since you use an infinite loop in `while True`).

Lastly, after you're done, you have a `list`. Since, presumably, you want to concatenate its contents back into a sentence, you can use `string.join`, which combines the contents of the `list` with `string` in between (here `''` is used, so there will be nothing between each element of the `list` in the final string)

For example:

```
translation_mapping = {'you': '你', 
                       'are': '是', 
                       'human': '人类'}
result = []

while True:
    input_string = input()
    if input_string == '_END':
        break

    try:
        result.append(translation_mapping[input_string])

    except KeyError:
        # input_string was not found in the translation mapping
        print(f"I didn't understand {input_string}. Please try again.")

print(''.join(result))
```

Output:

```
>>> you
>>> are
>>> a
I didn't understand a. Please try again.
>>> human
>>> _END
你是人类
```

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for a data structure.

If the user is entering just a letter, a list should be enough and do the job.

There are 2 issues with your program that we have to address.

1) Wrong equality operator.

You are using the equal operator instead of the == comparison operator. Which results in every condition being true, because you are setting a variable's value to be that value.

2) Wrong scoping.

Your variables L_1 and L_2 are being scoped only to the if/else conditional operator, and not to the function itself. Make sure you declare variables outside of your loop, so you can use them again when the loop is finished.

Comment: Actually, Python loops and `if` statements do not have their own scope, so the OP is fine in that regard.

Answer (score 0):

Fixing some of the Python code (equality operators etc), and adding an exit condition for the loop (user input starts with 0). This is not necessarily the best way of handling user input, but I wanted to keep it vaguely similar to the original code.

You want to create an empty list to store results, and `append` to that in each loop.

```
output_data = []
while True:
   i = input()
   if i[0] == "a":
       output_data.append("b")
   if i[0] == "b":
       output_data.append("a")
   if i[0] == "0":
       break
print(output_data)
```

Comment: User already admits he's a beginner - no need for the lead comment.

Comment: @colminator Fair call. Have edited. To the OP, this was not meant as a dig at you. We all started with similar code.

Answer (score 0):

```
print('Enter the number of letters')
n = input()
word=[]

i=0;
while(i<n):
    word.append(input())
    i+=1
```